# php preg_replace regular expression before and after

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i can't figure out how to preg_replace the following string:

```
$str = "01;01;0000000; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then ;1234;123; text and/or numbers and/or symbols 02;05;1111; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then ;4444;333; text and/or numbers and/or symbols 03;07;45457; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then ;4321;321; text and/or numbers and/or symbols ";
```

So I want to replace everything before and after `1234;123`. `1234` is always a sequence of 4 numbers and `123` is always a sequence of 3 numbers

here is part of the original string

```
$str= "01;01;249;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO 01;01;250;Caselho;;;;;;;;;;;3750;012;AGADÃO 01;01;251;Corga da Serra;;;;;;;;;;;3750;013;AGADÃO 01;01;252;Foz;;;123;;;;;3750;014;AGADÃO 01;01;253;Guistola;;;ni ;;;;;3750;015;AGADÃO 01;01;254;Guistolinha;;;;.;;;;3750;016;AGADÃO 01;01;255;Lomba;;;;-;;;;;3750;017;AGADÃO 01;01;256;Povinha;;;;;;;;;;;3750;018;AGADÃO 01;01;257;Vila Mendo;;;; ;;;3750;019;AGADÃO 01;01;258;Aguada de Baixo;;;;;;;;;;PC AGUADA DE BAIXO;3750;996;AGUADA DE BAIXO 01;01;258;Aguada de Baixo;;;;;;;;;;;3750;031;AGUADA DE BAIXO 01;01;260;Landiosa;;;::::;;;;3750;033;AGUADA DE BAIXO 01;01;262;Passadouro;;;;;;;;;;;3750;035;AGUADA DE BAIXO 01;01;263;Aguada de Cima;;;;;;**;;;3750;041;AGUADA DE CIMA 01;01;264;Aguadalte;;;;;-+;;;3750;042;AGUADA DE CIMA";
```

Comment: So you want to replace everything other than `\d{4};\d{3}`?

Comment: Replace with what?  And what about 4444;333 it's the same pattern?

Comment: exactly, everything other than \d{4};\d{3}

Comment: in the end i want something like 1234;123 1234;123 1234;123 1234;123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or to get them:

```
preg_match_all('/;([\d]{4};[\d]{3});/', $str, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Then you can use the array or implode them to create a string or whatever.

Comment: +1 altho I'd suggest using `\b` instead of the `;`, like `/\b\d{4};\d{3}\b/`.

Comment: @Qtax: Thanks, but it seems to be a repeatable structure with the ; as delimiter so more exact.

Comment: You can remove the [] characters.

Comment: in both of your and Lajos Veres it seem the script doesn't even load because the page just load in one second!

Comment: Then you have other problems.

Comment: no because i tried other regular expressions and i could see the result of them

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not a regex guru, but this works for me:

```
preg_replace('/()([0-9]{4};[0-9]{3})()/im', 'AAA', $yourString);

Outputs:
01;01;0000000; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then ;AAA; text and/or numbers and/or symbols 02;05;1111; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then ;AAA; text and/or numbers and/or symbols 03;07;45457; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then ;AAA; text and/or numbers and/or symbols
```

Comment: this is the contrary of what i want!

Comment: i want to replace the 01;01;0000000; text, spaces and many tipes of caracters like : . ; ' - and then